# MySQL ProgrammingError 1064, dealing with raw data

Tags: mysql, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to insert my data into a db that I have created, already. I have provided the schema to the db so it accepts varchar and text for the appropriate columns, and date/ integer for the other two. I am able to connect to my db, but am fighting with error messages and my code continues to fail based on my formatting. If anyone can guide as to how this can be changed, I would appreciate immensely! (I have commented out the try/ error, just to get the error message output when I run the code.)

```
   #open db connection
    db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', database='WebScraping')
    print(db)
    #prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()
    #prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database
    sql = "INSERT INTO WebScraping.Reviews(name, location, date, rating, content) VALUES ('{}', '{}', '{}', '{}', '{}')".format(name, location, date, rating, content)
   #try:
        #execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql)
   #commit your changes in the database
    db.commit()
    print("Record committed")
    #except:
        #Rollback if there is an error
        #db.rollback()
    #disconnect from the server
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use string formatting, use query parameters.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO WebScraping.Reviews(name, location, date, rating, content) 
         VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""
cursor.execute(sql, (name, location, date, rating, content))
```

If `date` is in the format `mm/dd/yyyy` you need to parse it with `STR_TO_DATE()`.

```
sql = """INSERT INTO WebScraping.Reviews(name, location, date, rating, content) 
         VALUES (%s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%m/%d/%Y'), %s, %s)"""
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried-- now I am getting a response that result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(params) -- InterfaceError: Python type cannot be converted. Is this my mysql data error or still with my syntax in the py code. Please pardon the silly questions, I am new to the coding world and trying to learn and understand as best as possible.

Comment: This sounds like a data error. What is the type of `content`?

Comment: I am inputting text in the form of string for the first 3, then a date (though in the form of mm/dd/yyyy). and a rating (integer, which has been converted in my script). Finally, content is also a string of text which I have as 'text' input in my table.

Comment: Edit the question and add the full traceback. Maybe it will have enough information to know which parameter is causing the problem.

Comment: MySQL expects dates to be in the format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: I appreciate the help, so much. GOing to try all of these!!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yelp2.py", line 77, in <module>
    get_reviews(review_page, rev_writer)
  File "yelp2.py", line 55, in get_reviews
    cursor.execute(sql, (name, location, date, rating, content))
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 248, in execute
    prepared = self._cnx.prepare_for_mysql(params)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 626, in prepare_for_mysql
    result = self._cmysql.convert_to_mysql(*params)

Comment: I am also writing these files to csv file, and also inputting into dict{}; not sure if either of these could be the reason?

Comment: review_dict = {}
        review_dict['name'] = name
        review_dict['location'] = location
        review_dict['date'] = date
        review_dict['rating'] = rating
        review_dict['content'] = content
        r_writer.writerow(review_dict.values())

The data I want to write to my db file is actually a list of items that need to be input.

Comment: I just noticed that I accidentally removed one of the `%s` during my earlier edit, so there were the wrong number of placeholders. Try it now.

Comment: If that doesn't fix it, try narrowing down the problem by retrying it with different columns removed, to see which one is causing the error.

Comment: No, other things you do with the data cannot have any effect on the database query.

Comment: I removed the content column and this is the problem-- I need to adjust the field for this, as it seems its too much text, perhaps?

Comment: The long block of text will still not be written as it is in a list--so this will need to be converted. I am thrilled, the rest is writing to tb.

Comment: Is it an ordinary text string, or a byte string?

Comment: It was just an ordinary text string. I was able to fix by str() on the list.

Comment: What list are you talking about? Is `content` a list of strings rather than a single string?

Comment: writing = str([r.text for r in review.find('p', attrs={'lemon--p__373c0__3Qnnj text__373c0__2Kxyz comment__373c0__3EKjH text-color--normal__373c0__3xep9 text-align--left__373c0__2XGa-'}).children]
        db = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', database='WebScraping')
    
        #prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
        cursor = db.cursor()
        #prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database
        sql = """INSERT INTO WebScraping.Reviews(name, location, date, rating, writing) VALUES (%s, %s, STR_TO_DATE(%s, '%m/%d/%Y'), %s, %s)"""

Comment: You probably want to use `"".join(...)` rather than `str()`